# Short Exact Sequence of Complexes Induces Long Exact Sequence of Homology Groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I am following Lang's Algebra on General Homology Theory and wanted to try proving the short exact sequence of complexes
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> A @>{f}>> B @>{g}>> C @>{}>> 0
\end{CD}$$
induces a long exact sequence on the homology groups
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 @>{}>> H^{i}(A) @>{}>> H^i(B) @>{}>> H^i(C) @>{\delta}>> H^{i+1}(A) @>{}>> H^{i+1}(B) @>{}>> H^{i+1}(C) @>{}>>
\end{CD}$$
by the snake lemma.
I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284654/prove-that-a-short-exact-sequence-of-chain-complexes-induces-a-long-exact-sequen) question regarding the same topic, and I am trying to flesh out the proof by following the comment noting the following diagram commutes and is exact in the rows.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
&&A_n/B(A_n) @>{f_{*}}>> B_n/B(B_n) @>{g_{*}}>> C_n/B(C_n) @>{}>> 0 \\
&@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>{}>> Z(A_{n+1}) @>{\alpha}>> Z(B_{n+1}) @>{\beta}>> Z(C_{n+1})
\end{CD}$$
I see how $f$ and $g$ induce homomorphisms $f_*, g_*$ by sending $f_*(a+B(A_n)) = f(a) + B(B_n)$ and similarly for $g$ (at least I think), but I cannot see how the top row is exact. I realize under the induced homomorphism $f_*$ we have $\text{Im}(f_*) = \text{Im}(f)/B(B_n)$ but I'm not sure how to prove this is $\ker(g_*) = g^{-1}(B(C_n))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably a quick proof by abstract nonsense, but I can't see that argument right now. However, when in doubt, a diagram chase always works in entry-level homological algebra.

The more difficult direction is $\ker{g_*} \subseteq \operatorname{im}{f_*}$. Let $[b] \in \ker{g_*}$ with $b \in B_n$, so $g(b) \in B(C_n)$, i.e. there exists $c \in C_{n+1}$ such that $g(b) = d(c)$. By exactness of $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ there exists $b' \in B_{n+1}$ such that $g(b') = c$. Because $g$ is a chain map, we have $$g(b) = d(g(b')) = g(d(b')) \implies g(b-d(b')) = 0.$$ Thus, $b-d(b') \in \ker{g}$, so by exactness there exists some $a \in A_n$ with $f(a) = b-d(b')$. But then $f([a]) = [b]$ which shows $[b] \in \operatorname{im}{f_*}$ as desired.

How did I find this proof? I really just followed my nose: I started taking the definition and writing down the only sensible thing one could do at each step. And just after a few lines we came to the desired conclusion!

In fact, it's probably easier to do this yourself than to read the proof of somebody else.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph: One can replace the set-theoretic diagram chase by an arrow-theoretic diagram chase but that's about it. A version of Snake Lemma still has to be proven regardless and I don't think there's a purely abstract way of doing this.

Comment: @mrtaurho Depending on what you mean by "purely abstract way", there are purely categorical proofs of the Snake Lemma. But anyway, this question was not about proving the Snake Lemma.

Comment: "Purely abstract" is not the best choice of words I reckon. What kind of categorical proof do you have in mind?

Comment: @mrtaurho Honestly, I just remember a tutor presenting a nice proof of the Snake Lemma but not the content haha. Probably something in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74871 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314693.

Comment: Yeah, that's the arrow-theoretic diagram chase I was refering to (a great account of this can also be found in the later chapters of Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0). To be fair, it's pretty abstract all ready. Still "elementary" diagram chases although this might just be the nature of the Snake Lemma :D

Comment: @mrtaurho I see. Thanks for the Aluffi reference! :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's the abstract proof I promised which I guess is the standard proof taught in homological algebra.

Consider the following commutative diagram which I copied from Weibel (p. 13) because I'm admittingly too lazy to draw a commutative diagram on MSE.

[image]

The middle two rows (involving just $A,B,C$) are exact and hence the Snake Lemma shows that the upper and lower row (without the zeros) are exact.